# Bootstrap carousel: sets active item to first when data changes (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

My carousel with data.img is an array of link img

```
   <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        className="codeinfo__carousel carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div className="carousel-inner">
          <div className="carousel-item active">
            <img
              src={data.img[0]}
              className="codeinfo__img d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          {data.img.map(
            (e, i) =>
              i > 1 && (
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img
                    src={e}
                    className="codeinfo__img d-block w-100"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                  {i}
                </div>
              )
          )}
        </div>
        <button
          className="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          className="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

When the data has changed, the active item does not return to the first item, but to the number of the previous active item. So if the length of the previous data.img is bigger than the length of the current data.img there will be nothing to display and the carousel will crash.(sorry for my english, I use google translate)
Like the example below. How to make class "active" return first item?
[carousel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3TuA.png) > Change data > [carousel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikIwg.png)

Comment: Are you using just plain Bootstrap with React? If it is just plain Bootstrap, it comes with some scripts of its own and maybe they override the classes you set in your React code.

Comment: Yes i just linked the bootstrap cdn in public/index.html. What should I do? I think should write something in useEffect(()=>{ },[data])

Comment: I removed the cdn link and used **npm i bootstrap, @popperjs/core**. the following code works roughly (return to the first value):
`useEffect(() => {  
    if (data !== null) {  
      var carousel =  new bootstrap.Carousel(document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls'))  
        carousel.to(0)  
    }  
  }, [data]);` However, in case the index value is greater than the length of the current data.img. Still the nothing shows up. [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#events)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. I removed all bootstrap actions and select active item using react code. I use useState to select active item, setInterval to autoPlay, useEffect to reset activity to 0. Here is my code:

```
const Carousel = (props) => {
  const data = props.data;
  const [nowActive, setNowActive] = useState(0);
  const [onHover, setOnHover] = useState(false);

  // autoplay (stop in hover)
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!onHover && data !== null) {
      let i = nowActive;
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
          if (i >= data.img.length - 1) {
            setNowActive(0);
            i = 1;
          } else {
            setNowActive((prev) => prev + 1);
            i = i + 1;
          }
      }, 3000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    }
  }, [onHover, data]);

  // change data >> return active = 0
  useEffect(() => {
    setNowActive(0);
  }, [data]);

  const carousel = () => {
    return (
      <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        className="codeinfo__carousel carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
        onMouseOver={() => setOnHover(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setOnHover(false)}
      >
        <div className="carousel-inner">
          {data.img.map((e, i) => (
            <div className={"carousel-item " + (nowActive === i && "active")}>
              <img src={e} className="codeinfo__img d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <button
          className="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            nowActive === 0
              ? setNowActive(data.img.length - 1)
              : setNowActive(nowActive - 1);
          }}
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>

        <button
          className="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            nowActive === data.img.length - 1
              ? setNowActive(0)
              : setNowActive(nowActive + 1);
          }}
        >
          <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
          <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return data !== null ? 
    <div>{carousel()}</div> :    
    <div>Null data</div>
```

***Note: Although the problem has been solved, but this carousel does not have any Animation Effect when changing slides:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Carousel has a property called defaultActiveIndex, which is the initial value of activeIndex. You can use it to focus on the correct CarouselItem

1. Create a new State:

   const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
2. Set the defaultActiveIndex to the newly created state:
3. Change the activeIndex whenever an item in the carousel is clicked:

   onClick={(e) => {   setActiveIndex(i);   }}

Honestly they should just make this default behavior, not sure why we have to hack it.